# "The force is strong with this one" --перевод

Tags: перевод

I'm wondering how to translate this Star Wars quotation.   Both "force" and "strong" are сила/сильный.  So I'm wondering how to translate the n a way that's not repetitive.

Comment: In the film it was "В нем чувствуется мощь Силы" as far as I remember.

Comment: yeah, it was worthwhile to actually listen to the Russian dubbing of the movie

Answer (score 1):

Normally requests for translation are considered off-topic here, but anyway

Here `strong` indicates a great(er) degree/amount of `force`, not strength in the literal sense, so

> **Сила его велика**

Comment: Not a good transaltion. It lacks a clear reference to the Force. "Сила его велика" can also just mean that this guy is strong (has tons of muscles).

Comment: not being an avid fan of the movie i didn't really consider the plot, but i believe it at least shows how do avoid repetitiveness